# Does a future tense sentence become untrue after the future point passed?

Tags: discourse-context

I said, “I will play piano,” and I did it. After then, does “I will play piano,” which was once a true sentence, become an untrue sentence because “I played piano” is a true sentence now?

Comment: This question is confusing.  Note that in your example, "I will play piano," in a sense, is not true until after you've done it.  Until then, it's just a promise or prediction.

Comment: These are questions of logic and philosophy rather than grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Do you find that strange?

If I have a plate I can say "It is a plate" and that is true.  If I break the plate, that makes "It is a plate" untrue. What was true at one time can be false later.

If I play piano on Wednesday Dec 3 2021 (and never again) then on Tuesday I can say "I will play piano" and it is true.  But on Thursday "I will play piano" is not true.

Perhaps you don't have grammatical tense in your language.  But suppose I say "Tomorrow I play piano."  That would be true on Tuesday, but not on Thursday.  Tense in verbs has just the same effect as time words like "Tomorrow".